# How to insert user registration data to non-drupal table

Tags: 7, users

I installed drupal 7.34 with oracle database. Now i need to save user registration data to another non-drupal table. User authentication also need to do with these non-drupal database field. Is there any method to generate the per-existing set of users in non-drupal database as drupal users.

Comment: Doable, but will require a lot of coding - obviously it is hard to expect anyone had exactly the same use case you do now, right? Have you started implementing it? Do you have a starting code and *specific* question? It's not possible in Q&A format to guide you all the way.

Comment: We partially succeeded to implement user login. Issues raised when we move into user registration.

Comment: What issues @drup? (please edit this information into the question)

Comment: I am getting this error. PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'DB.register' doesn't exist: INSERT INTO {register} (uid, name) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 11 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => test@test.com ) in register_user_insert() (line 8 of sites\all\modules\register\register.module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks similar to what happens when someone tries to access CiviCRM tables from Drupal when the CiviCRM tables exist in different database containers.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1569656.

Are these tables in the same database container or just on the same database server?

You may want to look at [How to use separate databases for Drupal tables?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60596/how-to-use-separate-databases-for-drupal-tables/60601)

It might also be worth looking at http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC44/Creating+a+Drupal+user+for+every+CiviCRM+contact

That gives both a manual process of generating Drupal users from a CSV export as well as the drush method.

Comment: Both drupal and non-drupal sites shares same database, but under different users. Like user1.table1 and user2.table2. Do i need to change DB schema for this non-drupal table to save my user registration details?

Comment: "Base table or view not found" means just that. With the db connection configured the way you have it, the db user running this query cannot "see" the table.  Since line 8 of https://www.drupal.org/project/register isn't a query, I'm assuming that this register.module is a custom module.  (FYI you should really prefix your custom modules so they don't conflict with exiting projects).  I don't know much about Oracle db permissions, but my guess is if you try to run the same SQL query that's in register_user_insert() directly using the same dbuser, it will return a similar error. Good luck!